# MongoJS returns no results while MongoClient does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to connect to MongoDB with Node.js. MongoClient works fine, but Mongojs doesn't:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var url = '...';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    var cursor = client.db("events").collection('events').find();
    cursor.each(function(err, event) {
        console.log("OK MONGODB");
    });     
});

mongojs(url, ['events']).events.find(function(err, events) {
    events.forEach(function(event) {
        console.log("OK MONGOJS");
    });
});
```

"OK MONGODB" is logged several times; "OK MONGOJS" is not.

What's wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `url` used in `MongoClient` should be different with `mognojs`.

Suppose the `url` is `'mongodb://localhost/'`, it is OK for `MongoClient`. However, the [`url` used in `mongojs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) should be added with dbname as following

```
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost/mydb', ['mycollection']);
```

So it should be as below

```
mongojs(url+'events', ['events']).events.find(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I still have a problem. I have 3 databases: admin, events and local. When I choose admin, it works but I don't have the collections that I want to access (they are in events). When I choose events, I get "MongoError: Authentication failed.". Do you know what I did wrong please?

Comment: @Arnaud, [Enable Client Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) of mongodb. you should connect mongo through [mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/connection-string/), please refer the link here.

Comment: I already use the connection string "mongodb://root:password@IP:27017", and this works for the admin database. Does it mean that I have to define a new user for the events database?